# Most Time efficient way to convert list to a dict of frequencies in Python?

Tags: python, performance

as the title states what is the fastest way to convert a list of strings to a frequency dict. I've been using this, but I figured this isn't probably a good option:

```
return dict(Counter(re.findall(f"(?={pattern})",text)))
```

Or, will a simple loop be better:

```
freq = {}
ls  = re.findall(f"(?={pattern})",text)

for l in ls:
    freq[l] = 1 if l not in freq else freq[l]+1 

return freq
```

Or are there better ways?

**Additionally:** What is the most ***space*** efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: why id `Counter`based approach not a good option?

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization to me. Do you have any evidence this is a significant bottleneck in your program?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I'm getting into Bioinformatics [Youtube, Coursera lol]. I beginning to understand that a vast majority of problems involve parsing through huge chunks of data to identify numerous patterns. As such, time/space efficiency seems to be the top priority. For simple programs like a Frequency Map such optimizations won't make a difference but I'm trying to focus on the optimizations early on for future problems

Answer (score 1):

Using a `collections.Counter` will be faster than a crude manual for loop - and since `Counter` is already a dict subclass you don't necessarily need to make it a plain dict either.

If you want to compare execution times of two snippets, you can easily do it using the `timeit` module:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

import timeit

text = """
as the title states what is the fastest way to convert a list of strings to a frequency dict. I've been using this, but I figured this isn't probably a good option. I'm getting into Bioinformatics [Youtube, Coursera lol]. I beginning to understand that a vast majority of problems involve parsing through huge chunks of data to identify numerous patterns. As such, time/space efficiency seems to be the top priority. For simple programs like a Frequency Map such optimizations won't make a difference but I'm trying to focus on the optimizations early on for future problems. as the title states what is the fastest way to convert a list of strings to a frequency dict. I've been using this, but I figured this isn't probably a good option. I'm getting into Bioinformatics [Youtube, Coursera lol]. I beginning to understand that a vast majority of problems involve parsing through huge chunks of data to identify numerous patterns. As such, time/space efficiency seems to be the top priority. For simple programs like a Frequency Map such optimizations won't make a difference but I'm trying to focus on the optimizations early on for future problems.as the title states what is the fastest way to convert a list of strings to a frequency dict. I've been using this, but I figured this isn't probably a good option. I'm getting into Bioinformatics [Youtube, Coursera lol]. I beginning to understand that a vast majority of problems involve parsing through huge chunks of data to identify numerous patterns. As such, time/space efficiency seems to be the top priority. For simple programs like a Frequency Map such optimizations won't make a difference but I'm trying to focus on the optimizations early on for future problems.
"""


def fast():
    return dict(Counter(re.findall(r"(\w)", text)))

def slow():
    freq = {}
    ls  = re.findall(r"(\w)", text)

    for l in ls:
        freq[l] = 1 if l not in freq else freq[l]+1 

    return freq


rf = timeit.timeit("fast()", "from __main__ import fast", number=10000)
rs = timeit.timeit("slow()", "from __main__ import slow", number=10000)

print("fast: {}".format(rf))
print("slow: {}".format(rs))
```

This being said:

> I'm getting into Bioinformatics. I beginning to understand that a vast majority of problems involve parsing through huge chunks of data to identify numerous patterns. As such, time/space efficiency seems to be the top priority. For simple programs like a Frequency Map such optimizations won't make a difference but I'm trying to focus on the optimizations early on for future problems – roy05 2 hours ago

While there are indeed some (sometimes very huge) performance gains to be had from using the correct data type (ie set vs list for containment testing) or implementation (ie list expressions instead of for loop + list.append), most of the time we are really bad at guessing where the real bottlenecks are, so you want to use a profiler to find out. Except for the couple obvious cases mentionned above, trying to optimize without profiling first is a waste of time.

More importantly ever, when it comes to "huge chunks of data", those kind of "optimizations" won't get you very far and the proper way to solve both time and space issues is massive parallelization (think map-reduce frameworks), which means you have to think the whole code architecture with this in mind right from the start.